# glassfish gem requires jdk 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glassfish, java

Hiee,

```
    I'm trying to work on RubyonRails, n installed the same with rubyinstaller. But, When i try to create a project, It gave me error as "glassfish gem requires jdk 6".
```

Can someone help me out of this, that how I proceed now..??

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the Java Development Kit if you really want to use Glassfish, from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html